# Adding space after // in clang format

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

I have a clang-format based off of LLVM but I found it surprisingly hard to find a setting to add space after comment start. Basically, I'd like to have:

```
// This is a comment
```

instead of:

```
//This is a comment
```

Here's the `.clang-format` I'm using at the moment:

```
# Generated from CLion C/C++ Code Style settings
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: Consecutive
AlignOperands: true
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Always
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Always
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
AlignTrailingComments: true
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel: false
  AfterClass: false
  AfterControlStatement: Never
  AfterEnum: false
  AfterFunction: false
  AfterNamespace: false
  AfterUnion: false
  BeforeCatch: false
  BeforeElse: false
  IndentBraces: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
ColumnLimit: 0
CompactNamespaces: false
ContinuationIndentWidth: 8
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentWidth: 4
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 2
NamespaceIndentation: All
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PointerAlignment: Right
ReflowComments: false
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: true
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 0
SpacesInAngles: false
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seems to be a `SpacesInLineCommentPrefix` option in Clang 13, see [docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html). However, as far as I can see, there's no such option in older versions.

If you have access to Clang 13 on your system, this is how you'd use it:

```yaml
SpacesInLineCommentPrefix:
  Minimum: 1
  Maximum: 1
```